# SolrCore Initialization Failures - Max direct memory is likely too low

Tags: java, hadoop, solr, solrcloud

I get this exception message during SolrCore initialization:

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   The max direct memory is likely too low. Either increase it (by adding
>   -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=g -XX:+UseLargePages to your containers startup args) or disable direct allocation using
>   solr.hdfs.blockcache.direct.memory.allocation=false in solrconfig.xml.
>   If you are putting the block cache on the heap, your java heap size
>   might not be large enough. Failed allocating ~134.217728 MB.

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

SOLR is caching HDFS index files off JVM heap in direct memory. It is running out of memory while doing so. You can disable direct memory caching by setting `solr.hdfs.blockcache.direct.memory.allocation=false`

in solrconfig.xml. This will cause SOLR to cache HDFS index file portions in heap, so it is important you check what is the size of your JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=20g` your `solr.in.sh` file to the variable `GC_TUNE`. (20g as the example in Solr Ref guide)

The `GC_TUNE` should look like:

```
        GC_TUNE="-XX:NewRatio=3 \
        ...
        -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled \
        -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=20g"
```